# UICustom cell not showing labels in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uilabel

I have added custom `UItableViewCell` with labels. Labels are visible iOS 6 but not in iOS 7.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{

   [super layoutSubviews];
   self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(90.0f ,-5.0f, 200.0f, 50.0f);
   self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(3.0f , 2.0f, 75.0f, 55.0f);

}


-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

   self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
   self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
   self.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.4 blue:0.7 alpha:0.9].CGColor;
   self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2;


   [self.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
   self.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

   [[UIColor grayColor] set];
   [videoDurationTextLabel  drawInRect:CGRectMake(90, 30, 190, 10) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];

    [videoFileSizeLabel drawInRect:CGRectMake(170, 30, 190, 15) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];


}
```

TableViewController class

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LazyTableCell";

    VideoCustomCell *cell = [self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[VideoCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}

cell.textLabel.text = videoRecord.videoTitle;
cell.videoFileSizeLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4lfMb",totalSpaceInMB];
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imgData]];
cell.videoDurationTextLabel = videoRecord.duration;
```

}

Comment: Have your tried setting the frame of the labels in the init method?

Comment: Check this link http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_custom_cells

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
[super layoutSubviews];
CGRect cvb = self.contentView.bounds;
CGRect imf = self.imageView.frame;
imf.origin.x = cvb.size.width - imf.size.width;
self.imageView.frame = imf;
CGRect tf = self.textLabel.frame;
tf.origin.x = 5;
self.textLabel.frame = tf;
 }

- (void) viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomTableCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomTableCell"];

 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";
CustomTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[CustomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.titleLabel.text ="test text";
[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData: imgData]];


return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to name your custom cell using your cell identifiers name.

As i see in your `UITableViewCell` code, your cell identifier name is `LazyTableCell`. Rename your cell to have the same name.